# Is there any compiler magic in PChar / PWideChar / PAnsiChar casts?

Tags: string, delphi, pointers, casting

I often read that the compiler does some kind of magic when casting to `PChar`.

The main purpose of `PChar` is to call foreign code in libraries that expect a zero terminated array of characters (C style "string").

`PChar` is a type that is an alias to `PWideChar` on Unicode Delphi and an alias to `PAnsiChar` on non-unicode Delphi.

Delphi strings (`string` = `AnsiString` / `UnicodeString`, I'm not talking about `WideString` here, let alone `ShortString` ...) on the other hand have a hidden length instead of a termination char. They are also reference counted and use copy on write.

Are Delphi strings automatically allocated and kept to be one char longer with an implicit #0 char in order to make casting to a `PChar` (PAnsiChar / PWideChar) easier or does the compiler check and adjust the string when it encounters a conversion to `PChar`?

Comment: I don't doubt that the primary reason **most** developers use `PChar` and its ilk is to call foreign code, but that's not their literal purpose. They are Pointer Types for the various String types defined in Delphi. From a technical standpoint, that's all they are.

Comment: @LaKraven All the magic around `PChar` makes it more than a mere pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The process is as follows:

- If a string `s` has length greater than zero, then `PChar(s)` returns a pointer to the first element of the string content. Because the `string` is managed to have a *hidden* null-terminator nothing more needs to be done.
- If a string `s` has length zero, then `PChar(s)` returns a pointer to a block of memory containing a null-terminator.

As an implementation detail, the null-terminator that is returned from `PChar(nil)` is a global constant allocated in the read-only section of the compiled module.

> Are Delphi strings automatically allocated and kept to be one char longer with an implicit #0 char in order to make casting to a PChar (PAnsiChar / PWideChar) easier?

Yes.

The magic, if you can call it that, is that:

1. Using `PChar()` on empty strings returns a pointer to a null-terminator.
2. Delphi maintains the *hidden* null-terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: @Jens - A 'compiler intrinsic' perhaps? When the compiler sees a PChar cast, it generates a call to '_UStrToPWChar' for instance.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz sounds reasonable. In laymans terms maybe "special handling"? After all compared to normal casts the compiler does something unusual here.

Comment: @Jens - It may b a better fit, yes. :)

Comment: Compiler magic is a commonly used term. In the documentation they use the term compiler intrinsic to mean the same thing. At least that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 3):

A string variable internally is a pointer into a structure containing prefix, characters and null terminator. Though the structure starts from the prefix (containing string length, ref count, char size and codepage) the pointer points to the first character, so casting to PChar is straightforward.

The magic behind of string -> PChar casting is that always `PChar(S) <> nil`, even if string is empty (`S = ''` and `Pointer(S) = nil`). Instead of returning a string variable pointer 'as is', like `Pointer(S)` do, `PChar(S)` calls a function that checks whether `Pointer(S)` is nil and if `Pointer(S) = nil` returns a pointer to a dummy empty string instead of `nil` (i.e. a pointer to the null terminator of the dummy empty string).

Comment: Here is a question with a nice answer by Rob Kennedy that explains the internal structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549469/what-happens-when-ansistring-is-cast-to-pansistring

Comment: And here is the official documentation for XE3: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types